# Performance of Join vs Subquery in Where Clause (HIVE)

Tags: hive, inner-join, where-clause

Can someone please help me understand which approach would be the most efficient.

The first table `users_of_interest_table` has one column `users` that has ~1,000 unique user ID's.

The second table `app_logs_table` has a `users` column as well as an `app_log` column.  The table has more than 1 billion rows and over 10 million unique users.

What is the most efficient way to get all the app log data for the users in `users_of_interest`.  Here is what I have come up with so far.

Option 1: Use Inner Join

```
SELECT 
  u.users, a.app_logs
FROM 
  users_of_interest_table u
INNER JOIN 
  app_logs_table a
ON 
  u.users = a.users
```

Option 2: Subquery in Where Clause

```
SELECT 
  a.users, a.app_logs
FROM 
  app_logs_table a
WHERE 
  a.users IN (SELECT u.users FROM users_of_interest_table u)
```

Comment: what is the size of your users table? does it only contains Ids?

Comment: The `users_of_interest` table contains only Ids and has 1,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

the community advises the use of the Join clause, but, in some tests that I have done, the In clause has been more efficient

You must do the test yourself, use the SQL Server Profile tool for this